# Binding a TextBox's Height to Parent via Code

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I have a TextBox that I'm creating, via code, to insert into a Control in a WPF interface. The Control can be dynamically resized via click-and-drag code, and I want the TextBox's height and width to match the Control's. The end result is that I have a TextBox that I can dynamically resize.

The box is going to be placed in this Border:

```
<Border Name="borInner" Margin="0,0,2,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

I'm trying to make the textbox fill the area of the border. To do so, I'm assuming 2 things have to happen.

1. I have to set Horizontal and Vertical Alignments on `borInner` to Stretch
2. The `TextBox` must also have those properties.

Unfortunately, when both of these things are set, the TextBox matches the Width of the overall control, but not the height. It just sits centered vertically still. Does the Height value of a TextBox control just not follow Stretch? If I set a height manually, it will work, but I'd rather not have to manually update the size of the textbox during the mousemove if I can help it, as it's pretty slow to calculate what the new dimensions should be constantly.

For more detail on the Control the TextBox is being inserted into: It has a property I've made called `bool FitContentToSize`, which makes this code happen on the Control's creation

```
borInner.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
borInner.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
```

I then create the textbox

```
element = new TextBox() {
            AcceptsReturn = true,
            TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap,
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto,
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch,
            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto
        };
```

and add that TextBox to `borInner`.

What am I missing, or does anyone have a decent idea for a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the height of the textbox to `Double.NaN` and then setting the margin to 0 all around.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your inner border (borInner) is not inside something like a StackPanel, or anything else that limits the height of its children to the bare minimum. If this is the case, consider using something like a Grid, or DockPanel.

Comment: It's in side of another border, which itself is in a grid (which is on the control). So, borInner->borVis->gridOuter->Control